# Create Job To Convert Data With SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I Want To Convert Data From OldDatabase To NewDatabase Each Day By SSIS.
for this:

```
1- Create Script From Exists New DataBase
2- Change DatabaseName OF Generated Script and Then Execute Script To Create NewDatabase2 whit no data.
3- Set SSIS Configuration Parameters.
4- Execute SSIS Package to convert Data.
```

I Want to do this action by Job.
How I want to do?

Comment: Is your goal just to create a copy of the database with a different name, or do you need to need to modify the data too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your requiremets are not very clear but there are two SSIS tasks that can help you.

If you want to transfer all you can use a "[Transfer Database Task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141204.aspx)"

If you need to specify objects, you can use the "[Transfer SQL Server Objects Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142159.aspx)" where you can specify things like if you are dropping the objects first and how to deal with the data:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. your method is best practices